# What are the differences between a 'formula' like $x^2+y^2=1$ and a 'function' like $y=f(x)=x^2$?

Tags: functions

A know it is a weird question but what are the differences between a 'formula' like $x^2+y^2=1$ and a 'function' like $y=f(x)=x^2$?

I know a formula can only be a function when each $x$ value outputs one and only one $y$ value and therefore $x^2+y^2=1$ cannot be a function since each $x$ values, except $1$, outputs $2$ $y$ values

but are there any distinct features or theorems that can only be applied to a function as result of this definition?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to get at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^2+y^2=1$ is an implicit function : if you give it a point $(x,y)$ it will tell you $YES$ or $NO$. Giving it many points in the plane and plotting only the points where the "function" told you $YES$ will give you a circle.

Implicit functions are "more powerful" than standard functions. For example, for a given $x$, there can be several $y$'s that will make the function say $YES$. On the other hand, standard function have only one $y$ for a given $x$ (or maybe none). You can always turn a standard function into a implicit function : $y = f(x) \Leftrightarrow y -f(x) = 0$. However you cannot always explicit an implicit function, or if you can it is usually more complicated. For example : $x^2 + y^2 = 1 \Leftrightarrow y = \pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$, this shows that there are actually two values of $y$ given an $x$ and the circle cannot be described by a standard function $y = f(x)$.

You can do calculus with implicit functions : For example [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).

Comment: Also, $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ is a (2D) function as well.

Comment: @naslundx I don't think so. The graph is still understood as a member of $\mathbb{R}^2$; the function $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$ would have a 3D graph. As zubzub says, $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is more implicitly saying $y = f(x) = \pm \sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant a 3D function.